# prove that $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ is continuous on rectangle R.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

where $R = \{(x,y): |x|, |y| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \}$

I am trying to use picard's theorem so I have to prove that f is continuous on R and that it's lipschitz continuous.

How would I do this? I know the definiton of continuity for two variables. But I don't know what I should let $\delta$ equal to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$.  We want to find a $\delta > 0 $ so that $|f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0)| < \epsilon $ whenever $\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2} < \delta$.

Now, $|f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0)| = |(x^2-x_0^2) + (y^2-y_0^2)|\leq |x-x_0||x + x_0| +|y-y_0||y+y_0|$

but $|x|,|x_0|,|y|,|y_0| \leq 1/\sqrt{2}$ so the expression above is bounded by $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}(|x-x_0| + |y-y_0|) \leq \sqrt{2} \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2}$

So just choose $\delta = \epsilon/\sqrt{2}$